# Errors in Sunflow rendering

Tags: java, rendering, raytracing

I have been working with the Sunflow rendering engine source and have noticed errors when using Point Lights,The errors are not there with any other light type,so trying to work out what it could be and whether i can fix it..

If you look at the images you can see the left edge of the Sphere is a dark area this happens with all shaders apart from mirror i just wondered if anyone has seen this or has any idea where i can start looking in the code to try and fix it.

Images use 3 Point lights and all colours are set to 0,0,255 including the mirror shader.

See picture [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/79306379@N04/8002781301/in/photostream).